# Lightning Arrow but the lightning does spawn in

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

So i got this code of somebody and he said it would work i was grateful (still am) but it seems that the code doesnt work in someway

This is my Main file

```
package me.Pixel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.entity.Arrow;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityShootBowEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    public Main plugin;
    public List<String> spells = new ArrayList<String>();
    public getTargets getTargets = new getTargets();

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        plugin = this;
        getCommand("bow").setExecutor(new BowCommand());
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityShootBow(EntityShootBowEvent event) {
       if(event.getProjectile() instanceof Arrow) {
            Arrow arrow = (Arrow) event.getProjectile();
            new LightningShot(arrow).runTaskTimer(this, 0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my LightningShot file

```
package me.Pixel;

import org.bukkit.entity.Arrow;
import org.bukkit.scheduler.BukkitRunnable;

public class LightningShot extends BukkitRunnable {

    private Arrow arrow;
    private int tick = 1;

    public LightningShot(Arrow arrow) {
        this.arrow = arrow;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (arrow == null || arrow.isOnGround() || tick++ > 20 * 10) {
            this.cancel();
        } else {
            arrow.getWorld().strikeLightning(arrow.getLocation());
        }
    }
}
```

To be clear [This is what i want it to look like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJD-4pWOwuQ) but then instead of an Snowball the arrow that comes out of the bow.
I hope you guys can help me. It would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you haven't registered your listener. Even though the listener is your main class you still need to register it in your `onEnable` method with:

```
this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
```

Then the code will spawn lightning at the arrow's location as intended (I tested the code).

Comment: Ty ty, can i ask you what guide or other source is awesome to learn this stuff from

Comment: If you google "bukkit listener", the top result is the [Event API Reference](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference) (it's always good to consult the API documentation first when looking for solutions). You can also always try googling the problem, sometimes you'll even find helpful tutorials, or look on the [Bukkit plugin development forum](https://bukkit.org/forums/plugin-development.5/).

Comment: If this answer helped solve your problem, could you accept it please? That way people will know your question is solved. Thanks!

Comment: Yea sure, i cant test it right now cuz im not home not xD in like 45 or 30 min i will accept it if its

Comment: Its gonna be towmorrow man im sorry i will test it first thing in the morning